# Given any set S of 6 natural numbers, must there be two numbers in S that have the same remainder when divided by 8?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Answer the following questions and justify your answer. 
Hint: Use the (generalised) pigeonhole principle.

Given any set S of 6 natural numbers, must there be two numbers
in S that have the same remainder when divided by 8?

My instinctive answer would be.... no? Since obviously, 'any' set of natural numbers could simply be 6 positive integers that do not have the same remainder when divided by 8. Of course, this being discrete math and not simple logic, I have to proof it.
So I suppose my question is how to apply the generalised pigeonhole princip to disprove that for S, {n, m} have the same remainder when divided by 8.

-Apologies in advance, as I can see the pigeonhole princip has been featured before. I just cant seem to make anything of it.

Comment: The answer is no. Simply $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ contradicts it. There should be some other conditions.

Comment: They probably want a set S of 9 natural numbers.  I bet it's a typo, twisting a "9" into a "6."

Answer (score 0):

Something is odd, on the face of it, about the "hint".

Here's a set of six natural numbers: $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ with different remainders when divided -- zero times! -- by 8.

So we have an immediate boring proof by counterexample that it is *false* that,  given any set $S$ of six natural numbers, there must be two numbers in $S$ that have the same remainder when divided by 8. The pigeonhole principle doesn't come into it!

(Was there a series of examples, perhaps, and you were supposed to spot which ones the pigeonhole principle is useful for??)

Comment: The problem is as simple as stated. It's one out of three questions, which may be why the pigeonhole principle is mentioned. Also, I'm assuming my professor wants a generalised answer and not a simple 'no'. I guess dividing 1-6 by 8 is a cheeky generalised answer. 

Here are the rest of the questions: 
(b) Given any set S of 10 natural numbers, must there be two numbers in S that have the same remainder when divided by 8? 
(c) Let S be a finite set of natural numbers. How big does S have to be at least so that it contains at least 5 numbers that have the same remainder when divided by 8?

Answer (score 0):

The key word here is *questions.*  Plural.

As you revealed in a comment, what you copied was part of a set of three questions. You need the Pigeonhole Principle for the questions in parts (b) and (c) of the problem. You don't need it for part (a) (the question about a set of six numbers), which has a simple counterexample.